# How can I simplifying code without duplication?

Tags: java

I was making a method that users take turns and removing stones and there are a lot same code repeating, just one thing is different (user name for each turn). so I think I can make it into half length simple code, but I'm not sure how I can do that. Is there a way to just get different user names in each turn without repeating same code twice? thanks in advance

```
int turn=0,n=0;
while (stoneNum>0)
{   
  if(turn==2*n-1&&stoneNum>0)
 {System.out.println(p1.getName()+"'s turn - remove how many? : ");
     remove = sc.nextInt();
     s.setStone(remove); 
     stoneNum = stoneNum-s.removeStone();
     showStones();
     if (!(stoneNum>0))turn=1;
     if (!(stoneNum>0)) break;}


if(turn==2*n&&stoneNum>0)
{System.out.println(p2.getName()+"'s turn - remove how many? : ");
       remove = sc.nextInt();
       s.setStone(remove);
      stoneNum = stoneNum-s.removeStone();
      showStones();
      if (!(stoneNum>0))turn=2;
      if (!(stoneNum>0))break;}
     }
```

Comment: How about using a variable that holds the current user or putting the duplicate code into a method and calling it with different parameters?

Comment: `for (Player p : Arrays.asList(p1, p2)) { ... your code, replacing p1/p2 with p .. }`.

Comment: turn is the only variable that's different.   Find a way to pass it into the method.  I/O should not be part of that method - no writing to the UI.  @AndyTurner is correct - I missed player p1 and p2.

Comment: Generally, if you have a substantially similar body of code repeated, then it should be a subroutine (=method in Java).  The different things that it operates on should be passed as arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your block into a loop:

```
for (Player p : Arrays.asList(p1, p2)) {
  int det = (p == p1) ? 2 * n - 1 : 2 * n;
  if (turn == det && stoneNum > 0) {
    System.out.println(p.getName() + "'s turn - remove how many? : ");
    remove = sc.nextInt();
    s.setStone(remove);
    stoneNum = stoneNum - s.removeStone();
    showStones();
    if (stoneNum <= 0) {
      turn = (p == p1) ? 1 : 2;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `stoneNum -= s.removeStone();`

Answer (score 0):

Removing duplicate code using one extra variable `flag`.

```
int turn = 0, n = 0;
    int flag=0;
    while (stoneNum > 0)

    {
        if (turn == 2 * n - 1 && stoneNum > 0) {
            System.out.println(p1.getName() + "'s turn - remove how many? : ");
            flag=1;
        } else if (turn == 2 * n && stoneNum > 0) {
            System.out.println(p2.getName() + "'s turn - remove how many? : ");
            flag=2;
        }
        remove = sc.nextInt();
        s.setStone(remove);
        stoneNum = stoneNum - s.removeStone();
        showStones();
        if (!(stoneNum > 0)) {
            turn = flag;
            break;
        }
    }
```